# XSLT transform siblings to children

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to do something tricky in xslt
I have a flat xml which contains a large list of siblings and depending on a name I want to transform them to children
General rules for my transformation are:

1. If tag/name is "BLOCK" then open a "BLOCK" element with tag/value as the attribute
2. If tag/name is "BLOCK_END" close the "BLOCK" element (
3. In all other cases create an element tag/name,put tag/value and immediatly close it

So for a following xml:

```
<message>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>first</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>FOO</name>
        <value>BAR</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>second</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>FOO2</name>
        <value>BAR2</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK_END</name>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK_END</name>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>third</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>FOO3</name>
        <value>BAR3</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK_END</name>
    </tag>
</message>
```

This is the result I am hoping for:

```
<message>
    <BLOCK id="first">
        <FOO>BAR</FOO>
        <BLOCK id="second">
            <FOO2>BAR2</FOO2>
        </BLOCK>
    </BLOCK>
    <BLOCK id="third">
        <FOO3>BAR3</FOO3>
    </BLOCK">    
</message>
```

I used the following xslt. This is working fine but sadly it finishes the execution after the encoutering the first BLOCK_END tag

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <message>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="message/tag[1]" />
    </message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
    <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tagValue" select="value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$tagName = 'BLOCK'">
            <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tagValue"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::*[1]" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$tagName = 'BLOCK_END'">
            <!-- DO NOTHING-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$tagValue"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::*[1]" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks to **BitTickler** I am getting closer but still not quite there.

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, Altova, XmlPrime?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sadly no, I'm stuck with core XSLT 1.0

Comment: Instead of "DO NOTHING" in the BLOCK_END, I would try something like ``<xsl:call-template ... select="./following-siblings::*" >`` as you wish to return from the current recursion and then continue with the remaining tags.

Comment: Also, I have my doubts about the initial ``<xsl:for-each ...>`` statement as this is quite imperative and already a hint that this approach will cause trouble. Instead you should apply the template for the first tag element and then let the recursive calls work their wonders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact, that the recursive template calls serve 2 purposes (1 too many):

1. Proceed the cursor into the input tag elements by one towards the end.
2. Handle the nesting level for the output.

For that to work, it is necessary to "return" both the current output state and the "iteration" state from the recursive function (template).

In a functional language, this can be demonstrated, e.g. with the following short code, emulating the situation.

```ml
type Node = 
    | Simple of string * string
    | Nested of string * string * Node list

let input =
    [ 
        Simple ("BLOCK","first")
        Simple ("FOO","BAR")
        Simple ("BLOCK","second")
        Simple ("FOO2","BAR2")
        Simple ("BLOCK_END","")
        Simple ("FOO3","BAR3")
        Simple ("BLOCK_END","")
    ]

let rec transform (result,remaining) =
    match remaining with
    | [] -> result,remaining
    | x::xs -> 
        match x with
        | Simple (n,v) when n = "BLOCK" ->
            let below,remaining' = transform ([],xs)
            transform (result @ [Nested(n,v,below)],remaining')
        | Simple (n,v) when n = "BLOCK_END" ->
            result,xs
        | Simple (n,v) ->
            transform (result @[x],xs)

transform ([],input)
```

Now that there is 1 solution strategy which works, the only question remaining is, how to apply this strategy to xslt transformations.

To kick start the whole thing, probably the first `<tag>` element should be transformed. And within its transformation the recursion happens.

The BLOCK_END should somehow return from the recursion such, that the current position is known, so the BLOCK section can resume at that point later on.

My best guess so far looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="message">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/message/tag[1]" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nest" match="tag">
  <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="name"/>
  <xsl:variable name="tagValue" select="value"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./name='BLOCK'">
      <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$tagValue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::tag[1]" />
      </xsl:element>
      <!--TODO: We must continue here with the remaining nodes. But we do not know  how many 
      Nodes the block contained... Our cursor (.) is unaffected by previous recursion. -->
      <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::tag[1]" />-->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="./name='BLOCK_END'">
      <!--No nothing-->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$tagValue"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::tag[1]" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Producing the output:

```xml
<message>
   <BLOCK id="first">
      <FOO>BAR</FOO>
      <BLOCK id="second">
         <FOO2>BAR2</FOO2>
      </BLOCK>
   </BLOCK>
</message>
```

Comment: Many fair points - specially the ones in the comment. Thanks to your suggestions I feel I'm getting closer. I am having doubts on calling the template after "END_BLOCK". The whole point is to "exit the recursive call" so that </xsl:element> does it's magic. If I make another recursive call after "END_BLOCK" then I iterate through the whole doc before closing the <BLOCK> element. Please check my updated description

Comment: @DannyBoy Yes you do not want to enter another recursion. But you want to advance ``.`` somehow. Maybe you need to switch to ``<xsl:cal-template name="nest"> <xsl:with-param...> ... `` constructs entirely. If there is no other way to do that. The param then contains e.g. the following sibling or so.

Comment: took me more than expected but I managed to find the solution. In the TODO section I look for "closing" tag and re-initialize the loop for the next sibling after the closing tag. Works like a charm. This was quite a cool problem and couldn't have done it without all your help! Many thanks!

Comment: @DannyBoy Either post your solution as an answer, or edit this one. Otherwise this is not helping anyone.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a shorter way, but this still seems to me to be the most straightforward approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child-item" match="tag[not(name='BLOCK')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tag[name='BLOCK'][@level=current()/@level][1])" />

<xsl:key name="child-block" match="tag[name='BLOCK']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tag[name='BLOCK'][@level=current()/@level - 1][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/message">
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass-rtf">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag[1]" mode="first-pass" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass" select="exsl:node-set($first-pass-rtf)/tag" />
    <!-- output -->
    <message>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass[name='BLOCK'][@level=1]"/>
    </message>
</xsl:template>

<!-- first-pass templates -->
<xsl:template match="tag[name='BLOCK']" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="level" select="0"/>
    <tag level="{$level + 1}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </tag>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tag[1]" mode="first-pass">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <tag level="{$level}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </tag>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tag[1]" mode="first-pass">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag[name='BLOCK_END']" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tag[1]" mode="first-pass">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level - 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- output templates -->
<xsl:template match="tag[name='BLOCK']">
    <BLOCK id="{value}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child-item', generate-id()) | key('child-block', generate-id())" />
    </BLOCK>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
    <xsl:element name="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will start by rewriting you input as:

```
<xsl:variable name="first-pass-rtf">
    <tag level="1">
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>first</value>
    </tag>
    <tag level="1">
        <name>FOO</name>
        <value>BAR</value>
    </tag>
    <tag level="2">
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>second</value>
    </tag>
    <tag level="2">
        <name>FOO2</name>
        <value>BAR2</value>
    </tag>
    <tag level="1">
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>third</value>
    </tag>
    <tag level="1">
        <name>FOO3</name>
        <value>BAR3</value>
    </tag>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then it becomes simple(r) to associate each `tag` to its parent block.

Answer (score 0):

The end solution was an extension upon BitTickler's idea:

I had to twick the original xml so that the end block tag also contains an identifier (we use it to search the corresponding END_BLOCK tag for the BLOCK tag)

```
<message>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>first</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>FOO</name>
        <value>BAR</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>second</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>FOO2</name>
        <value>BAR2</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK_END</name>
        <value>second</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK_END</name>
        <value>first</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK</name>
        <value>third</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>FOO3</name>
        <value>BAR3</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>BLOCK_END</name>
        <value>third</value>
    </tag>
</message>
```

Then the trick was to do a recurrent call of the template for the END_BLOCK + 1 tag (see "magic" comment). There is no benefit of doing the "call-template" (just some leftover trial-and-error on my side) and I will revert it back to "apply-templates"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <message>
            <xsl:call-template name="transformTag">
                <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="message/tag[1]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </message>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="transformTag">
        <xsl:param name="tag"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="$tag/name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tagValue" select="$tag/value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$tagName = 'BLOCK'">
                <!-- OPEN A BLOCK, RECURENTLY CALL FOR THE NEXT ELEMENT AND THEN MAKE A RECURENT CALL ONCE AGAIN FOR THE NEXT BLOCK-->
                <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tagValue"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:call-template name="transformTag">
                        <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="$tag/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:element>
                <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS-->
                <xsl:variable  name="closingTag" select="$tag/following-sibling::*[name='END_BLOCK' and substring-before(value,'@@')=$tagValue][1]"/>

                <xsl:if test="$closingTag/name='END_BLOCK'">
                    <xsl:variable name="nextTag" select="$closingTag/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$nextTag[name() = 'tag']">
                        <xsl:call-template name="transformTag">
                            <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="$nextTag"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$tagName = 'END_BLOCK'">
                <!-- DO NOTHING AND EXIT THE RECURENT CALL (THIS CLOSES THE TAG)-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- PRINT THE REGULAR TAG AND RECURENTLY CALL FOR THE NEXT TAG-->
                <xsl:element name="_{$tagName}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tagValue"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:call-template name="transformTag">
                    <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="$tag/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*had to twick the original xml*" This makes it a completely different question. When we answer XSLT questions here, we assume the input XML schema is given. If you do have the ability to modify it to your liking, why not make it actually easy to process?

Comment: "had to twick the original xml" does not mean "I am the one who generates the xml and can make the structure as I please". What I meant is that my original xml is much more complex and has much more data to it. In this SO question I've filtered the xml to catch the essence of my problem. Luckily the "closing block identifier" was something I had available but I omitted it initially as I (mistakenly) thought it was irrelevant